# AutoCompleteBox Take TOP10 or start populating when 3 letters

Tags: c#, wpf, autocomplete, filter, filtering

I have AutoCompleteBox with itemssource binding to collection. Now, in textChanged evend I'd like to populate when:

- autoComplete.Text.Length > 3 - have no idea if it possible to do this.
- take top10 results from my collection which contains autocomplete.text. This one I've tried like:

> myAC.ItemsSource = myList.Where(x =>
>   x.name.Contains(myAC.Text)).Take(10);

Unfortunately, with this solution I cannot change selected item(actually when I press up/down arrow I can select only first and last item).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `MinimumPrefixLengthProperty` property of autocompletebox to show results if text length >3.

Comment: Great, didn't know about it. Thanks!